# extract last line in linked list

Tags: c, algorithm, linked-list

My `clean_stash(list **stash)` function takes a pointer to a linked list
the linked list contains strings of `buff` size which are extracted from a bigger string `str`.
for example:

```c
typedef struct node
{
    char *content;
    struct node *next;
} list;
char *str = "atomic\nhabits";
int  buff = 5;
```

by that the linked list `stash` will contain:

```c
         +-------+---+     +--------+---+     +-----+------+
stash    | atomi | @ |---->| c\nhab | @ |---->| its | NULL |
         +-------+---+     +--------+---+     +-----+------+
// let's don't care about the code behind filling the linked list, I tested it and it works fine
```

the `clean_stash` function will delete the all the text but the last line
so the result will be:

```c
         +----------+------+
stash    | habits\0 | NULL |
         +----------+------+
```

this is my `clean_stash` function:

```c
void    clean_stash(list **stash)
{
    list    *last;
    list    *clean_node; // from ato\nmic to mic
    int     i;
    int     j;

    clean_node = malloc(sizeof(list));
    if (!stash || !clean_node)
        return ;

    clean_node->next = NULL;
    last = ft_lst_get_last(*stash);
    i=0;
    while (last->content[i] && last->content[i] != '\n')
        i++;
    if (last->content && last->content[i] == '\n')
        i++;

    clean_node->content = malloc(sizeof(char) * ((strlen(last->content) - i) + 1));
    if (clean_node->content == NULL)
        return ;
    j = 0;
    while (last->content[i])
        clean_node->content[j++] = last->content[i++]; 
    clean_node->content[j] = '\0';

    lst_display(clean_node); //this works as expected
    free_stash(*stash);
    *stash = clean_node;
    lst_display(clean_node); //this doesn't work at all
}
```

I created a `clean_node` of type `list` and coppied in it the last line in `stash` and all of that worked fine. I used `lst_display` function to display the content of the `clean_node` and I got my expected output(a node containing the last line)
the problem started when I freed the `stash` pointer and tried to assigne the `clean_node` to it. I used a `free_stash(*stash)` function.

```c
void    free_stash(list *stash)
{
    list    *current;
    list    *next;

    current = stash;
    
    while (current)
    {
        free(current->content);
        next = current->next;
        free(current);
        current = next;
    }
}
```

and that deleted both my stash and my `clean_node`. I don't know why it deleted my clean_node.
and that's what confused me for 3 days :)
I thought the problem is in this line `clean_node->content[j++] = last->content[i++];`
so I changed it with `strcpy(clean_node->content, (last->content+i));` but that didn't work too
I need help please can anyone explain this to me?
Thanks in advance.
Edit:
`ft_lst_get_last` return a pointer to the last element in the list:

```c
list    *ft_lst_get_last(list *stash)
{
    list    *current;

    current = stash;
    while (current && current->next)
        current = current->next;
    return (current);
}
```

lst_display just displays a linked list:

```c
int lst_display(list *lst)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    printf("/////////// list /////////////\n");
    while (lst)
    {
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, lst->content);
        lst = lst->next;
        i++;
    }
    printf("///////// end of List //////////\n");
    return (i);
}
```

Comment: Share `lst_display()`. `this works as expected` meaning you get `habits` as output? But if `ft_lst_get_last()` returns the last node, which doesn't have a `'\n'`, how does it work? I would rather stitch all texts across the list & call `memrchr()` to get your last line; if total text/content size is small.

Comment: Need definition of `ft_lst_get_last()` as well.

Comment: @SparKot I added the requested function check the code, and yes as u guessed `ft_lst_get_last` returns the last node in a list but it doesn't depend on if it ends with '\n' or not. That doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for some reason my `free_stash` function was deleting my `clean_node` list while I was trying to free the `stash` list, clean_node and stash are two separate lists they're not related to each other at all. despite of that it get's deleted when I pass `stash` to the `free_stash()`
I still need an explanation why that happened
but I solved the problem with changing my `free_stash` function to

```c
void free_stash(list **stash)
{
    list *current = *stash;
    list *next;

    while (current != NULL)
    {
       next = current->next;
       free(current);
       current = next;
    }
    *stash = NULL;
}
```